# wcf callback slow server response

Tags: wcf, callback

Can someone please give me a hint what is the main module in wcf callback (notification) which affects fastness and slowness of the broadcast response in client.

Here, the code used net.tcp. if ever my question is not that clear please let me know. I surely missed something.

-Sel

Answer (score 0):

The timeout, or amount of time that WCF will wait for a response from the service before throwing a TimeoutException, is controlled via the service binding configuration.

See this article for more information.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/